# Reading output audio data from Spotify Web Playback stream

Tags: javascript, spotify, web-audio-api

I am currently playing around with audio visualization and I am trying to work with Spotify's Web Playback SDK to stream and analyze songs directly on my site.

However, I am unsure what the limitations are when it comes to actually reading the streamed data. I've noticed that an iframe is generated for the Spotify player, and I've read that spotify uses the encrypted media extensions to stream the audio on chrome.

Is it even possible to read the music data from the Spotify api? Maybe, I can read the output audio from the browser?

Comment: I would assume you can't, in order to prevent pirating the music

Comment: Yeah that would make sense. It would also explain the lack of visualizers for Spotify on the web right now.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [web API documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/), you aren't able to play back full songs and get the audio data like you desire (for obvious reasons). Although, 30 second "song previews" are allowed through URL streaming, as well as full song playback on desktop browsers (excluding safari at the time of this post), with the [Web Playback SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/).

However on the mobile API it is now possible to get the raw PCM data ([Android](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android-sdk/) or [iOS](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios-sdk/)). This will require you registering for a developers account and setting up the access tokens if you haven't already done so.

For quick reference, on Android it involves using the [AudioController](https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/player/com/spotify/sdk/android/player/AudioController.html) class.

**EDIT** : Thanks to @Leme for the [Web Playback SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/)  link.

Comment: It actual is possible to get full song play back using the Web Playback SDK. [Web Playback](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/)

Comment: Apologies @leme I've updated my post to change the wording slightly. For the OP's purpose, they cannot use it to obtain the raw Audio data for analysis. So far the [web playback](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/) also only seems to support desktop environments.

Comment: Hey is this still possible with the AudioController class? I can't find any documentation on that or did they removed it?